# Adding a where to a nested query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want some help with a WHERE clause $start date is set further up in the code, and the query works when running against SQL from within Laravel. I get an error saying that $startdate isn't set. I am not sure that I am even doing WHERE correctly.

```php
$query = DB::query()
    ->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
    ->fromSub
    (function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) {
            $query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
                ->from('mytable')
                ->where('created_at', '>=', $startdate)
                ->groupBy('user_id');

        }, 'CC')
    ->groupBy('CC');

$result = DB::connection('mysql2')->select($query->toSql());
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code to see where $startdate is declared.

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql.

Comment: Thanks the SQL works ```SELECT CC AS CountOfVisits, Count(CC) AS Users
FROM
(
 SELECT user_id, count(user_id) AS CC FROM mytable
 WHERE created_at <= '2019-10-29' AND created_at >= '2019-10-01'
 GROUP BY user_id
) AS CC
GROUP BY CC;```

the issue is getting the variable into the function. I tried ```function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) use($startdate) {``` but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `fromSub` is an `anonymous function`, also known as a `closures`. It does not know about variables that you define outside of the closure. You can read more about them [in the official PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Rewrite your query to:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql2')
    ->query()
    ->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
    ->fromSub(function($query) use ($startdate) {
        $query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
            ->from('mytable')
            ->where('created_at','>=',$startdate)
            ->groupBy('user_id');
        }, 'temp')
    ->groupBy('CC')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, i tried this and it returns SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Comment: well that’s a different error from your original post. if you need help with your query you’ll have to give us more info and paste more code as you only pasted partial code. also please post the full error that you are getting not just the code

Comment: Error: ```Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (HY000)
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select `CC` as `CountOfVisits`, count(CC) AS Users from (select `user_id`, count(user_id) AS CC from `mytable` where `created_at` >= ? group by `user_id`) as `CC` group by `CC`)```

Comment: ```$startdate = $request->startdate;

        $query = DB::query()
            ->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
            ->fromSub
                (
                    function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) use ($startdate) {
                        $query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
                        ->from('establishment_checkins')
                        ->where('created_at','>=',$startdate)
                        ->groupBy('user_id');
                
               }, 'CC')
->groupBy('CC');```

Comment: $startdate = '2019-10-17'

Comment: Running this query against the database returns the correct result

```SELECT CC AS CountOfVisits, Count(CC) AS Users
FROM
(
 SELECT user_id, count(user_id) AS CC FROM mytable
 WHERE created_at <= '2019-10-29' AND created_at >= '2019-10-01'
 GROUP BY user_id
) AS CC
GROUP BY CC;```

Comment: Check my updated answer. That error is because you were doing `->select($query->toSql());`. toSql() only gives you the SQL with placeholders `(?)`. Try what i posted

Comment: FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Connection::prepareBindings() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/app/portal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 665

Comment: Can you [join me on chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201061/58441786) please?

Comment: I need to have 20 reputation :(

Comment: I have only just joined so reputation is low.

Comment: ```public function search(Request $request) {
$startdate = $request->startdate;
$result = DB::connection('mysql2')->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
->fromSub
(
function (\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query) use ($startdate) {
$query->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
->from('ebdb.establishment_sessions')
->where('created_at','>=',$startdate)
->groupBy('user_id');
}, 'CC')
->groupBy('CC')
->get();```

Thank you heaps for helping me

Comment: you're a legend thank you so much for helping me with this one! your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this here for others who find this page. It should be noted that `fromSub()` can also take a Builder object instead of a closure.

```
$builder = DB::table('mytable')->where('created_at', '>=', $start_date)
   ->select('user_id', DB::raw('count(user_id) AS CC '))
   ->groupBy('user_id');

$query = DB::query()
    ->select('CC AS CountOfVisits', DB::raw('count(CC) AS Users'))
    ->fromSub($builder, 'temp')
    ->groupBy('CC');
```

In my case, I already had a Builder object that I wanted to use in a sub select.